# Making join on 2 tables with millions record to be faster

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have two tables

**security_stat** => having 4 millions record

**security_trade** => having 10 millions record

I have this query running successfully but how can i **OPTIMIZE** this to be able to at least query 100,000 record within 10 seconds ( is it possible? ).. Currently it is very very slow.

```
SELECT `sec_stat_sec_name`, `sec_stat_date`, `sec_stat_market`, `sec_trade_close`, `sec_stat_date` 
FROM security_stat` LEFT JOIN `security_trade` 
ON `security_trade`.`sec_trade_sec_name` = `security_stat`.`sec_stat_sec_name` 
    and `security_trade`.`sec_trade_date` = `security_stat`.`sec_stat_date` 
limit 100,000
```

I have INDEX on sec_trade_sec_name, sec_stat_sec_name, sec_trade_date , sec_stat_date

I tried limiting result with *WHERE sec_stat_date >= 2005-01-01*  but that doesn't help much. (my records range from 1975 - 2014)

**EDIT**

security_stat schema

```
CREATE TABLE `security_stat` (
  `sec_stat_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sec_stat_date` date NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_sec_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_sec_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_market` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_industry` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_sector` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_subsector` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_sec_type` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_status` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_benefit` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_listed_share` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_earn_p_share` decimal(12,5) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_value` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_p_of_earn` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_as_date` date NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_div_p_share` decimal(16,12) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_p_of_div` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_end_date_div` date NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_pe` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_pbv` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_div_yield` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_par_value` decimal(16,5) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_market_cap` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_turn_ratio` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_npg_flag` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_acc_div` decimal(16,12) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_acc_no_of_pay` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_div_pay_ratio` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `sec_stat_earn_date` date NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `sec_stat_ev` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sec_stat_ev_revenue` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sec_stat_ev_ebit` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sec_stat_ev_ebitda` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sec_stat_earning_yield` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sec_stat_ps_ratio` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sec_stat_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sec_stat_date_name_id_cap` (`sec_stat_date`,`sec_stat_market`,`sec_stat_sec_id`,`sec_stat_sector`),
  KEY `sec_stat_date` (`sec_stat_date`),
  KEY `sec_stat_sec_name` (`sec_stat_sec_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3598612 ;
```

security_trade schema

```
CREATE TABLE `security_trade` (
  `sec_trade_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sec_trade_date` date NOT NULL,
  `sec_trade_sec_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `sec_trade_sec_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sec_trade_market` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `sec_trade_trading_method` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `sec_trade_trade_report` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `sec_trade_prior_date` date NOT NULL,
  `sec_trade_prior` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `sec_trade_open` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `sec_trade_high` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `sec_trade_low` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `sec_trade_close` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `sec_trade_last_bid` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `sec_trade_last_offer` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `sec_trade_transaction` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sec_trade_volume` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `sec_trade_value` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL,
  `sec_trade_avg_price` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`sec_trade_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sec_trade_close` (`sec_trade_date`,`sec_trade_sec_name`,`sec_trade_market`,`sec_trade_trade_report`,`sec_trade_trading_method`),
  KEY `security_trade_sec_trade_sec_name_index` (`sec_trade_sec_name`),
  KEY `security_trade_sec_trade_date_index` (`sec_trade_date`),
  KEY `security_trade_sec_trade_prior_date_index` (`sec_trade_prior_date`),
  KEY `security_trade_sec_trade_close_index` (`sec_trade_close`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10019817 ;
```

My Final query will actually have more

```
WHERE sec_stat_earning_yield IS NULL
ORDER BY updated_at ASC
```

but because when i add this two statement into the query with LIMIT of 1,000 records it make my query even slower ( may be because i didn't have index on this two columns? )

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Run `explain select ...` to see for yourself

Comment: What indexes do you have on the tables?  Do those indexes correspond to the join and or your where clause?  You specify a limit of 100k records, but there is no order by clause *(Do you want a random 100k records, the most recent 100k records, etc, etc?)*  You don't specify the schema, so we can't tell if `sec_trade_sec_name, sec_trade_date` is unique in one and/or other of the tables.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I updated my question with schema. I actually want to have one more WHERE clause and order by updated_at but that makes my query even SLOWER , (may be because i don't have **index** on those column? )

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is pretty much meaningless

Comment: (and I'm so glad I don't have to work with this naming convention)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try createing indexes to match the join so:

security_trade  (sec_trade_sec_name, sec_trade_date)

security_stat (sec_stat_sec_name, sec_stat_date)

or possibly

security_stat (sec_stat_earning_yield, sec_stat_sec_name, sec_stat_date)

And as pointed out in the comments above, your "Limit" clause may cause the result set to be not clearly defined.

Comment: I think i'm not much good with indexes but isn't already I have indexes on sec_stat_sec_name and sec_stat_date  looking in my schema above  
  KEY `sec_stat_date` (`sec_stat_date`),
  KEY `sec_stat_sec_name` (`sec_stat_sec_name`)

Comment: You need one index that incorporates multiple fields in the correct order. Two independent indexes will not help that much. Also run "Explain select" to see which indexes are being used.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the following as your actual query:

```
SELECT `sec_stat_sec_name`, `sec_stat_date`, `sec_stat_market`, `sec_trade_close`, `sec_stat_date` 
FROM `security_stat` LEFT JOIN `security_trade` 
ON `security_trade`.`sec_trade_sec_name` = `security_stat`.`sec_stat_sec_name` 
    and `security_trade`.`sec_trade_date` = `security_stat`.`sec_stat_date` 
WHERE sec_stat_earning_yield IS NULL
ORDER BY updated_at ASC
limit 100,000
```

You filter the `security_stat` table in two ways:
1. Only where `sec_stat_earning_yield IS NULL`
2. First 100k records when ordered by `updated_at`

***Note:*** I've assume you mean `security_stat.updated_at`, but you don't make that clear.

In order to make that as cheap as possible add an index that covers both of those fields `(sec_stat_earning_yield, updated_at)`.

***Note:*** Adding indexes that change a lot, especially when the order of the records changes within the index, can make a INSERTs slower.  *You* will need to balance INSERT performance against SELECT performance.

Then you join the trades table on, and so you want that lookup to be as fast as possible, which can be achieved with an index on that table covering `(sec_trade_sec_name, sec_trade_date, sec_trade_close)`.
- The first two fields in the index make the lookup simpler
- The last field in the index means the DBMS can avoid having to look in the table

Once done you may also be well served looking at the EXPLAIN plan, although relatively complicated it will give you key information to understand the best places to target your optimisation.